# I want to be forgotten according to Art. 17 GDPR. What is the correct procedure?

Tags: gdpr, germany

## English

I want to send someone a letter:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> In accordance with [Art.15 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-15-gdpr/), I ask you to inform me whether you are storing data about me.
>
> If you do this, I ask you (and third parties with whom you have shared data about me), in accordance with [Art. 17 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-17-gdpr/), to delete this data about me.
>
> In accordance with [Art. 19 GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/art-19-gdpr/) I ask you to inform me about the progress of this action.
>
> Regardless of whether you had already saved data about me or not, I ask you (and third parties with whom you have shared data about me), after you replied to me, to delete the data I submitted in this letter, that is, my address and my name, in accordance with Art. 17 GDPR.
>
> MFG Nils Lindemann

I am doing this for the first time, is that correctly worded, or do I have to proceed differently in order to be forgotten?

---

## Deutsch

Ich möchte jemandem einen Brief schicken:

> Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,
>
> Entsprechend [Art.15 DSGVO](https://dsgvo-gesetz.de/art-15-dsgvo/) ersuche ich Sie, mir Auskunft darüber zu erteilen, ob Sie Daten über mich speichern.
>
> Falls Sie dieses tun, ersuche ich Sie (und Dritte mit denen Sie Daten über mich geteilt haben) entsprechend [Art. 17 DSGVO](https://dsgvo-gesetz.de/art-17-dsgvo/), diese Daten über mich zu löschen.
>
> Entsprechend [Art. 19 DSGVO](https://dsgvo-gesetz.de/art-19-dsgvo/) ersuche ich sie, mich über den Fortgang dieser Aktion zu informieren.
>
> Unabhängig davon, ob sie bereits Daten über mich gespeichert hatten oder nicht, ersuche ich sie (und Dritte mit denen Sie Daten über mich geteilt haben), nachdem Sie mir geantwortet haben, die von mir in diesem Brief übermittelten Daten, sprich meine Anschrift und meinen Namen, entsprechend Art. 17 DSGVO ebenfalls zu löschen.
>
> MFG Nils Lindemann

Ich mache das zum ersten Mal, ist das so korrekt formuliert, oder muss ich anders vorgehen, um vergessen zu werden?

Comment: Is "speak/sprich" in the final paragraph(s) a typo?

Comment: @Rock Ape Yes, it is. I fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the form letters from the consumer advice center, e.g. [Lower Saxony](https://www.verbraucherzentrale-niedersachsen.de/themen/internet-telefon/musterbriefe-internet-telefon/musterbriefe-datenschutz).

Keep in mind that the entity may be allowed/required to keep **some** of your data. Anything that impacts their taxes, for starters. And your information/deletion request might also have to go on file, to mirror their record of a before-due-date deletion.

Comment: Does **some** of my data usually include my telephone number? And if so, are entities allowed to use it to contact me for advertising purposes (I guess not, just asking to be sure)?

Comment: phone numbers? that's a different question (to which the answer is https://www.frankfurt-main.ihk.de/recht/themen/wettbewerbsrecht/unlauterer_wettbewerb/telemarketing/ )

Comment: @Trish Superb, that's what I wanted to know

Comment: @NilsLindemann, as Trish points out having and using those numbers are different questions. **If** the entity is allowed to retain your data at all, then reasonably it must retain enough to identify you among other people with similar names. "Hello, I'm Hans Mustermann, please delete my data. What, there are a dozen of us? Well, *any* data on *any* Hans Mustermann, then."